# how can i send 4 files as multipart post request in Karate, i have tried

Tags: json, karate, multipart, multipartfile

``I have tried method1

```
 Given url urlUP + querykey
And header Authorization = auth.getBearerToken('Profile',keyClock)
And multipart file files = { read: '#(file1)' , read: '#(file2)' , read: '#(file3)' , read: '#(file4)' , contentType: 'application/json' }
When method post
```

Then status 200

method2

```
* def filepathtblBooking = 'src/test/file1.json'
* def filepathtblStatus = 'src/test/file2.json'
* def filepathtblBuilding = 'src/test/file3.json'
* def filepathtblRoom = 'src/test/file4.json'
```

Given url urlUP + querykey

And header Authorization = auth.getBearerToken('Profile',keyClock)

And multipart file files = { read: '#(file1)' , contentType: 'application/json' }

And multipart file files = { read: '#(file2)' , contentType: 'application/json' }

And multipart file files = { read: '#(file3)' , contentType: 'application/json' }

And multipart file files = { read: '#(file4)' , contentType: 'application/json' }

When method post
Then status 200

both failed

i have tried both ways API is not hit

Answer (score 0):

Refer documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#multipart-files

And here is an [example](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/753792dbd21b1d8f3fe69bd798daa26945b691da/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/upload/upload-multiple-files.feature).

If you mean an array of files with the same name, we just realized this is not supported, but this will be [available in the next release](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2171).

Comment: thanks so much Peter Thomas , yes we need to pass array of files with same name.... thanks so much!

Comment: when can we expect that .. current version  is 1.4.0   from 
 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-core

Comment: @RateeBhatt could take 2 weeks for the next RC - you could build from source if you want, that will help us verify also: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide - I also think you are not referring to the files via `read()` correctly, refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#path-prefixes